# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to create a custom Spinner component for my App, So I have created

**spinner.component.ts**

```
export class SpinnerComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild("spinner") spinner: ElementRef;

    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.spinner.nativeElement.style.display = "none";
    }

    public show = (): void => { this.spinner.nativeElement.style.display = "block"; };

    public hide = (): void => { this.spinner.nativeElement.style.display = "none"; };

}
```

**spinner.component.ts**

```
<img #spinner src="assets/images/dotSpinner.gif" class="loading"/>
```

And I'm trying to control this spinner in my other components, like

**sample.component.ts**

```
import { SpinnerComponent } from "../spinner/spinner.component";

export class SimpleComponent {

    private spinner: SpinnerComponent = new SpinnerComponent();

    constructor() {}

    actionHandler = (data: any): void => {
        this.spinner.show();
        this.clientActionService.subscribe(
            data => {
                this.spinner.hide();
                this.clientAction = data;
            },
            err => {
                this.spinner.hide();
            }
        );
    }

}
```

But I'm getting error
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at SpinnerComponent.show**

Comment: You should not create component instance manually. Either use query(ViewChild,ContentChild) or  DI mechanism as suggested above.

Comment: I tried it, but I'm getting error like ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SimpleComponent -> SpinnerComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SimpleComponent -> SpinnerComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for SpinnerComponent!

Comment: I did registered it on app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

**spinner.component.ts**  *// html code*

```
 <img *ngIf="isShowSpinner" src="assets/images/dotSpinner.gif" class="loading"/>

 <button (click)="show()"> Show </button>
 <button (click)="hide()"> Hide </button>
```

**spinner.component.ts** *//typescript code*

```
public isShowSpinner: boolean = false;
constructor() { }

public show() { this.isShowSpinner = true; }    
public hide() { this.isShowSpinner = false; }
```

**Please try this.**

Comment: Methods are calling but not able hide / show the spinner Img

Comment: are you which method use "show" and "hide" function called ? (ex. onclick, click, change)

Comment: On click() on Sample Component I am trying to call show() of Spinner Component

Comment: Thanks @Bhavin but We cannot have buttons on spinner component, I want to handle the spinner from other components,like when api call triggers we need to show the spinner indicating the user to wait, when api call is complete we can hide it

Answer (score 0):

If you want workaround then

```
<img
    [ngStyle]="{'display': displayVal}"
    src="assets/images/dotSpinner.gif"
    class="loading"/>
```

Typescript code

```
display = "none";
public show = (): void => { this.displayVal = "block"; };
public hide = (): void => { this.displayVal = "none"; };
```

Comment: Methods are calling but not able hide / show the spinner Img

Answer (score 0):

Use forwardRef

> forwardRef is used when the token which we need to refer to for the
>   purposes of DI is declared, but not yet defined. It is also used when
>   the token which we use when creating a query is not yet defined.

```
   import { SpinnerComponent } from "../spinner/spinner.component";   
    export class SimpleComponent {   
        constructor(constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => SpinnerComponent )) private ref:any)) {}

        actionHandler = (data: any): void => {
            this.ref.show();
            this.clientActionService.subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.ref.hide();
                    this.clientAction = data;
                },
                err => {
                    this.ref.hide();
                }
            );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Getting ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SimpleComponent -> SpinnerComponent]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SimpleComponent -> SpinnerComponent]: NullInjectorError: No provider for SpinnerComponent!

Comment: add SpinnerComponent as entryComponent in appModule

Comment: ya did registered SpinnerComponent as entryComponent in appModule but still no luck